# average number of swaps in dutch national flag

Tags: algorithm, sorting, dutch-national-flag-problem

I just want to know how can I get the average number of swaps in the two colors dutch national flag. sorting positive and negative numbers instead of colors. I'm assuming that the negative numbers are equal to the positive numbers and the array's numbers are given a random configuration, I'm not sure if my assumption is correct.

```
Algorithm(A[0…n-1]):
    i ← 0
    j ← n - 1
    while i ≤ j:
        if A[i] < 0:            
           i ← i + 1
        else:
           swap(A[i], A[j])
           j ← j - 1
```

Thank you.

Comment: Only two colors?

Comment: yes. in this case moving negative numbers to the left, and the positive numbers to the right

Comment: So if `n` is 32, then there must be 16 negative numbers and 16 positive numbers?

Comment: Well, you didn't answer my question, so I won't bother to answer yours. The fact is that your algorithm is suboptimal (assuming an equal number of positives and negatives in the array). And if you fix the algorithm, then the analysis of the algorithm becomes trivial. Good luck!

Comment: apologize, I wasn't around. yeah exactly, I'm just assuming that this is the only way to get the average number of swaps is to let the number of negative numbers is equal to the positive numbers. I'm not sure if my assumption is correct and that's why I post the question. Again, I apologize for the late reply

Comment: @user3386109: "your algorithm is suboptimal": can you substantiate ?

Comment: FWIW, monte carlo indicates that the average number of swaps is `(n-1)/2` using the algorithm in the question.

Comment: For the case where you don't have the same number of negative and positive values, you can reduce the number of swaps with: `if A[i] < 0: i <- i + 1; elseif A[j] >= 0: j <- j - 1; else: swap(A[i], A[j]);`, and you just need to loop `while i < j` (for the case with the same number of negative and positive values the number of swaps is the same, so it is more generic, I guess).

Comment: @user3386109: wrong, the average is exactly `n/2`.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Wrong, because you never have to swap the last element, i.e. the expected number of swaps for an array of length 1 is 0, not 1/2.

Comment: @YvesDaoust You are correct that I removed the `=` since it makes no sense to swap an element with itself.

Comment: @jdehesa: the question is not about improving the algorithm. It is about the number of swaps *as is*.

Comment: @YvesDaoust It was you that asked how the algorithm was suboptimal. jdehesa's comment answers that.

Comment: @user3386109: I know (though you were unable to tell it), and discussing optimality of the algorithm is irrelevant to the question. It even leads some to give a wrong answer.

Comment: @YvesDaoust It depends on whether the algorithm was written by the OP, or whether the algorithm was given as part of the homework. If the algorithm was written by the OP, you may have helped him analyze his flawed algorithm, without actually helping him find the right answer to his homework.

Comment: @user3386109: bad faith has invincible power.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the distribution of the positives and negatives is uniform, the first element is positive with probability `1/2`. After the first iteration, the array is shortened by one element and the distribution of the subarray is still uniform (moving an element is a neutral operation).

There are exactly `n` iterations before the subarray is empty thus the average number of swaps is `n/2`. More precisely, the number of swaps follows a Binomial law with parameters `1/2`, `n` (this is a Bernouilli scheme).

Comment: great explanation.  Wonder what will be the answer for 3-color `Dutch Flag` then.  (math part).   Thanks.